# How do I install wsl on a PC with a clean install of Windows 11 using ubuntu.tar, an image file created and saved on a previous PC?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Clean install Windows 11 to replace Mother Board.

There is an image file, image_file.tar, created for migration on the previous PC, so on the new PC

```
$ wsl --import Ubuntu-22.04 N:\WSL\Ubuntu-22.04 N:\WSL\ubuntu.tar --version 2
```

When I try to install with $ wsl.exe, I get a message about how to use wsl.exe and cannot import.

When I look on the net, I often see how to start with `$ wsl --install`, but I can't seem to find a way to install from the image_file.tar where my settings are saved.
How can I install from a .tar file?

Comment: Tar is an archive. One generally either mounts it or untars it to a directory. What does the wsl.exe message say?

Comment: You will see how to INSTALL with wsl.exe as follows -> 

Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument].

Arguments: --install

    --install <Options>
        Installs Windows subsystem features for Linux. If no options are specified,
        recommended features will be installed along with the default distribution.
        ...

    --list, -l [Options]
     ...

    --status
     ...

    --help
     ...

Comment: You should probably be installing normally then untaring your settings over the install.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to $ wsl --install first and then $ wsl --import as you said.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the Comment, $ wsl --import was not possible in the clean install state, but after $ wsl --install first.

```
$ wsl --install # install ubuntu by wsl
```

Reboot and enter username, password

WSL2 shutdown

```
$ wsl --shutdown
```

Check WSL2 running status. it will be Stopped. NAME at this time is the distribution to be removed.

```
$ wsl -l -v
```

Remove distribution from C drive

```
$ wsl --unregister Ubuntu # -> Use NAME displayed by wsl -l -v
```

then import

```
$ wsl --import Ubuntu-22.04 N:\WSL\Ubuntu-22.04 N:\WSL\import_image.tar
```